# Django : Add post id to the slug only if it already exists

Tags: django, django-models

Here is my code to generate slug,in models.py,

```
def save(self):
   self.slug = slugify(self.title)
   super(Post, self).save()
```

I want to check if the slug already exists in my database or not and then only add the id to that slug.

Only way I can think of now is to add id in every slug by doing this,

```
def save(self):
   super(Post, self).save()

   if not self.slug:
      self.slug = slugify(self.title) + "-" + str(self.id)
      self.save()
```

The problem is, it adds id in all the slugs.

So how can I check if a slug already exists due to same title and then only add the id to the new slug?

Comment: The problem with using the `id` in the slug is that you need to save the model first to get an `id`. If you set constraints on slug field, like it must be unique and it cannot be empty, then you have a chicken and egg problem if the slug is a duplicate because you cannot save it to access the id. It’s better to just append a simple number to the slug.

Comment: I am just practicing few things, this is one of the thing I was trying out. But, I will keep your suggestion in mind.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check if there is a post with the slug already exists then you can add id to the slug.

```
def save(self):
    # calling super so that the instance will get created and self.id will be accessible.
    super(Post, self).save()
    if not self.slug:
        slug = slugify(self.title)
        try:
            post_obj = Post.objects.get(slug=slug)
            slug += "-" + str(self.id)
        except Post.DoesNotExist:
            pass
        self.slug = slug
        self.save()
```

Though this code will work. But I prefer keeping the logic of creating slug in Post/Pre Save Singal model.

Comment: This code won’t work. super() should be called at the end (instead of `self.save()` so you’re not unnecessarily saving the `post` twice and to avoid an endless loop. It would probably even fail if the slug already exists and if a `unique` constraint was set. This could also be done in a `pre_save` signal (not a `post_save`).

Comment: @dirkgroten if the slug already exists then the control will not go inside if condition due to this condition `if not self.slug:`(I think you missed this line). I said I prefer post_save signal because models instance is available in the signal receiver so that instance.id can be accessed easily.

Comment: @dirkgroten Thanks for pointing out I updated the answer. Now, it will not save the model twice unnecessarily

Comment: I am calling super only when the object is getting created for the first time. If I move super call at the end then self.id is will not be available.

Comment: No you just had to move the call to save() inside the if clause. Remove the check for `self.id` and it will be correct. `super()` should be called regardless of the `id` being there or not because of the way he wants the slug.

Comment: Fixed it. Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: Your answer is correct. Just one thing, I have the redirect from the post creation form as `return redirect('webapp:detail', obj.slug)`. Because the slug is not created first, so I can't  redirect directly to the detail page. Is there any solution for that?

Comment: Slug will be created instantly after you create Post. So I don't think this problem will occur.